# Getting Null value on parameter in querystring parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my application i have send one link to User's email  id  he can download software on clicking this link....now  my url is look like....
http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=11/04/2013%2012:29:20%20PM&ProductName=Otja
and my code for retriving this value on pageload  download.aspx page is

```
    string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;



    string myDate = Request.QueryString["period"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDate))
    {
        myDate = myDate.Replace("!", ":");
    }
    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan variable = dt2 - dt1;
    if (variable.TotalMinutes > 5)
    {
        //Response.Write("Download time is expired now");
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "Download time is expired now";
    }
    else
    {

        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "U can Still Download";
    }
```

but this is not working  i tested  and before 5 Minute and after  minutes it is only shows  "You can still download"  so i think my error  is  that i can not retrive  that productname and period value on querystring on this download.aspx page..please help me.. thanks 
i think  there should be error..... String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  thats why it is pass null value  so any solution ???

Answer (score 1):

You said you think that your code is not able to retrieve the query params. Why don't you confirm that by printing the values first.

The Request.QueryString() looks correct.

There could be issue with your logic which may case the else to execute.

Based on more information provided by you please try this -

Variable myDate value must be “11-04-2013 06 36”. Please confirm.

Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);` try this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: actully sir  i tested this    make code response.redirect("download.aspx,false)  on that page where i have pass this url and make code for send mail and putting debugger on download.aspx  and after checking i saw  both the querystring pass null value ..

Comment: In your comment the download.aspx url does not have any parameters.

Comment: that is the reasion sir if i put parameters then its working but i can not do this thing because after click of submit button on inquiry page  that url is send autometically  to user's mail account and  download process is start  so i can not redirect user  to that download page so i can not pass that code  i have just pass for testing

Comment: i have to find another way  to  retrive this value  ....my logic is working because i checked after puting parametes on response.redirect its all working fine....but this is not requirement of my code

Comment: @BhushanBhangale Gudhi padawyachya hardik shubhechha. +1

Comment: i think  there should be error..... String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  thats why it is pass null value  so any solution ???

Comment: Why don't you show us what are you receiving? Also its not really very clear what you are doing? Please edit the question again and rephrase it properly with correct information.

Comment: http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=11-04-2013%2006%2036&ProductName=Otja i m getting output like this..and it shows error  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. my input url is   mail.Body += string.Format("<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh mm") + "&ProductName=" + productName + "\">Demo Download</a>");